# Creating a query that checks for new data every day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if I could get help on an issue I'm having with automating a query in SQL Server 2008. My goal is pull relevant customer data across from multiple tables in a DB using "CUSTOMER_ID" to link all the tables at the WHERE clause. In addition, I'd to automate this query so it runs every day, pulling the information entered from the previous day and exporting it to an excel file, where it is apprehended to the already collected information.

Now here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
[table1].CUSTOMER_ID AS "Customer ID",
[table2].CUSTOMER_ROOM AS "Room", 
[table3].LAST_NAME AS "Last", 
[table3].FIRST_NAME AS "First", 
[table3].SEX AS "Sex", 
[table3].AGE AS "Age", 
[table4].CHECK_IN_TIME AS "CheckIn", 
[table4].CHECK_OUT_TIME AS "Checkout",
[table4].HOTEL_LOCATION AS "Hotel", 
[table4].HOTEL_ID AS "Hotel ID", 
[table5].PLANE_ARRIVAL AS "Plane Arrival", 
[table5].PLANE_DEPART AS "Plane Departure", 
[table6].LOG_CREATE_TIME
FROM 
[table1]
INNER JOIN 
[table2] ON [table2].CUSTOMER_ID =[table1].CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN 
[table3] ON [table3].CUSTOMER_ID =[table1].CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN 
[table4] ON [table4].CUSTOMER_ID =[table1].CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN 
[table5] ON [table5].CUSTOMER_ID =[table1].CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN 
[table6] ON [table6].CUSTOMER_ID =[table1].CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE 
[HOTEL_ID] LIKE '02%' AND 
DATEPART(year, [table6].LOG_CREATE_TIME)=2015 AND
DATEPART(month[table6].LOG_CREATE_TIME) between 04 and 05 AND
[table4].HOTEL_LOCATION= '003'
```

The above statement pulls the information I need but it returns duplicate information in some cases and I would like a nudge in the right direction as how should I edit the DATEPART(LOG_CREATE_TIME) portion at the end so it's just looking for the new entries that came in the previous day. As of now, I'm obviously just pulling entire months just to test my query.

As for the automation, I plan on using the SQL Server 2008's export wizard to point it to an Excel file and then just telling SQL Server Agent to run the SSIS package every night but issue that I'm seeing right now is that this approach overwrites the previous information contained within the excel file. Is there no way to apprehend the new information to the file?

Comment: As far as automation goes, you can append to existing data in excel file as long as it is in .csv format (within SSIS package).

Comment: You really should use proper join syntax instead of the old style joins. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Row_Number() and that SQL is just too ugly from me to touch

Comment: Thank you for the much needed reading Sean Lange. I've updated my OP to reflect the usage of the INNER JOIN syntax.  I also which I could be as cool as Blam. Guy must get all the females with his "ha, I know something you don't" strut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your DATEPART question, try this:

```
AND [table6].LOG_CREATE_TIME between convert(date, getdate() -1) and convert(date, getdate())
```

Just remove your month and year DATEPART statements. This will return every record with a LOG_CREATE_TIME starting from midnight yesterday to midnight today. This should solve your duplicate data issue assuming a few things:

1. You run the script only once a day, no more.
2. You do not run the script at midnight while records are inserting into the log at that exact time.
3. New records that are entered into table6 use something like the getdate feature for the LOG_CREATE_TIME and that value is not changed after insertion.
4. You change those cross joins to something else. Cross joins are trouble and I don't think they're giving you what you think they are. Use inner joins instead.

You may consider tracking which records have been exported using a bit field, and changing your query to pull all records that have not yet been exported.

Comment: I like the idea of using a bit field but I assume that would be accomplished by creating a necessary column within this DB? That would be a no go as the structure of this table can't be edited in anyway.  If it could, I would clean up a bit of the syntax.
                                                                                                              And you're 100% on my cross joins. Will be spending a good portion of tomorrow reading up on proper join syntax. Thanks for setting me up on the right path on how pull the wanted data and Sean for providing the needed reading.

Comment: Correct, adding a bit field would be modifying the table. I assume if you cannot modify the table structure, then you will not be able to create other tables either, so maybe tracking which data you have exported in the database is out of the question. You might revisit the idea of tracking your records in some way if you continue to get duplicates, or find that you are missing records after exporting.